# Is there a way to communicate Alfresco Repository with an external app server?

Tags: share, alfresco, cmis

The idea of my project is to communicate Alfresco Share with my app server, but I found that Share only can communicate with Alfresco Repository, and to do the manipulation I said before I must develop all APIs that let the Share communicate with my app server. Since Share communicates only with Alfresco Repository, I'm searching a way to communicate my server app with this Repository, so my documents will be in Alfresco server and Share can then expose them. If I'm missing something to understand please correct me.

Can anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess what you are asking is "how to communication with an alfresco backend ?". If yes, you can use the REST API or CMIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jeff Potts mentioned in his last book:

Alfresco provides four main ways to develop your own UI:

- Share customizations
- Angular applications using ADF [Application Development Framework](https://community.alfresco.com/community/application-development-framework)
- Any JavaScript framework (using the [Alfresco JavaScript API](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-js-api))
- Any application capable of using the CMIS protocol

Comment: Hi Oussama. Thank you for the reply. I don't really get your point. I already have my application developed with UI and server. I just want alfresco Share explore my documents, for that I'm searching a way to connect my server to Alfresco Repository. Please explain to me if I misunderstood something.

Comment: Hi @progM, if you want to create an explorer in your own application you shouldn't think in Share, you should use ADF (if you are using angular) or the js API to easily consume Repository web services and create you explorer, there is a full documentation of this API on github, I think you will use [Content Services](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-js-api/tree/master/src/alfresco-core-rest-api)

Comment: The idea is not creating a new explorer, but using Share like explorer for my documents residing in my app server.

Comment: It's not you question, in this case you shoud deploy (or add) yours documents in Alfresco

Comment: The problem is I want to do this automatically not manually. For example, if I add a document in my app server automatically must be added in alfresco repository too. Because of that I said that I want to communicate my app server with alfresco repository. I'm searching if there is already some configuration or a connector to do so. If not how to do it ? Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: You can do this operation by using the Alfresco js API, you can find in the community many examples of uploading content in Alfresco using js API

Comment: I will search for that. Thank you so much for taking time to answer my questions @Oussama.